# Firefox 51.0.x Developer Tools Opens with every new site

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

The new Firefox dev tools (replacement for Firebug) console opens each time I access a new web url. It's a real pain. Is this happening to others? I've tried a clean install and full reset of Firefox and it still happens.

Comment: Are you saying your issue is that the DevTools *stay* open when you transition the single tab to a new URL, or that they open (from not already open) whenever you load a new URL, no matter what tab you open it in? Also, please be specific as to which DevTools you are talking about: Web Console, Browser Console, etc.

Comment: Can you close the DT by clicking on `X button` or using `F12`?

Comment: You already mentioned that you re-installed Firefox, but maybe you should try to `Refresh` Firefox as well, the easiest way, head over to https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/ & click on `Refresh Firefox`.

Answer (score 0):

The activation model of the Firefox DevTools is different to the one of Firebug.

Firebug's [activation model](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Activation) is based on URLs following the same origin policy, meaning, when you open Firebug on `http://example.com`, it will open again when you visit a subsite of it like `http://example.com/some/site`, even when you are in another tab.

The DevTools' activation model is based on tabs, i.e. when you open them in one tab, they stay open for all pages in this one tab, and they are not automatically opened in another tab.
There is already a [request for them asking to additionally support Firebug's model](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1284012).